# Reduce memory usage in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, ionic-framework

I am working on an app using ionic framework which pulls content from my backend system. I have a map as well and to reduce network usage I am saving content in module.factory (not sure if this is good for mobile app) and call api once when required. I am seeing my memory usage is almost 200mb in xcode and was wondering how can I reduce this. I was thinking of destroying scope ($scope.$destroy and also delete $scope) when each controller starts but it is not working.

Comment: This is probably related to Angular.js, not Ionic. Have you tried the Batarang extension?

Comment: I am very new so to angular and ionic. I am installing batarang right now.

Comment: i have tried batarang extension and I dont see scope from another controller which is good. I am thinking to set factory stored variable to null hopefully that might reduce memory usage. i would rather have more network usage than memory. I will try and update this post if it worked. If you guys have any suggestion please let me know